# Flutter pass a function to TextEditingController(text)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function

```
String test() => 'test';
```

and I'd like to pass it to the text argument of `TextEditingController` just like this one.

```
final TextEditingController _form1 = TextEditingController(text: test() );
```

but I got this error message.

```
"The instance member 'Test' can't be accessed in an initializer.
 Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression"
```

How can I fix it? also, why is this happening? Thanks!

Updated

---

I moved the function out to Class level and it works. At least with the example.

```
String test() => 'test';

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}


class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  Future _signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
  final TextEditingController _form1 = TextEditingController(text: test() );
  ...
```

That example works perfectly. Thing is that my let's called `test()` function, isn't as simple as return a String, but this one.

```
 String uid2str(String uid) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Usuarios')
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data()['InfoUser'];
        return '${data['Nombre']} ${data['Apellido']}';
      } else {
        return 'undefined';
      }
    });
  }
```

```
final TextEditingController _form1 = TextEditingController(text: uid2str(userID) );
```

For this case, it doesn't work, I tried using await/async but it seems text can't get a type which isn't not String. So Future can't be used.

I also can't use initialValue in my TextFieldForm because I have already a controller, and it seems I can't have both of them.

Answer (score 3):

Scince `test()` is a function, it can return dynamic values. So it cant be accessed in an initializer. There are several ways to replace it:

1. Add this code to your `constructor` or `initState`.

   ```
   final TextEditingController _form1 = TextEditingController(text: test() );
   ```
2. If the String is always the same,

   ```
    final TextEditingController _form1 = TextEditingController(text: 'test' );
   ```
3. Use a `textFormField` instead of `textField`,

   ```
    TextFormField(
      //your code
      initialValue = test(),
    )
   ```
4. set the test in your `constructor`,

   ```
    _form1.text = test();
   ```

There may be other possible ways too!

Comment: I tried moving the function out to Class level, and I can call it. The example works perfectly, the thing is, my real function doesn't work, and I think it is because is faster to show the text than my function trying to get the name from a user in firestore. I tried using await/asing but it can't be used because text is waiting for a string and not a future<string>, I'm gonna update with the function tho...

Comment: Yeah, it works if it is called outside of the class, because it is initialized before the TextEditingController . When you have them on the same class, the function is not yet built to be called in TextEditingController . So it throws an error. It is not the problem of firestore.